# How to call wait_event_interruptible from different file.

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm using wake_up_interruptible in ISR this is in file1.c and wait_event_interruptible is in file2.c.

file1.c looks like this.

ISR_handler()

{

......

......

wake_up_interruptible(&my_wait_queue);

......

......

}

And file2.c looks like this.

fun()

{

......

......

wait_event_interruptible (my_wait_queue);

......

......

}

My question is whether its possible to use wake_up_interruptible in one file and wait_event_interruptible in another file?
If not then what is way in which I can use wait_event_interruptible in different file.

Comment: In your current code you call these functions from different files. So, what is a **problem**?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, In my code i'm calling as i aforesaid , however my question is whether linux allow to do it or not ?

Comment: Hm, so wording "is it **allowed**" in the question post would be more precise than current "is it *possible*".